# How to migrate fragment syntax in Thymeleaf 3.x from version 2.x

Tags: spring, boot, spring-thymeleaf

Upgrading a Spring Boot project from 2.x to 3.x using Thymeleaf HTML pages.
Having a problem when current fragment expression includes a text modifier.

Set in application.properties file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
```

Current POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<!-- Thymeleaf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

SB 2.x version of fragment:

```
 <head th:replace="fragments/global/head :: head_default(title='Home')"></head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-nav-container">
            <header th:replace="fragments/global/header :: header_default"></header>
            <nav th:replace="fragments/global/nav :: nav_default(active='Home',subactive='Home')">      </nav>
        </div>
```

SB 3.x version of fragment:

```
<head th:replace="~{fragments/global/head :: head_default(~{title='Home'})}"></head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-nav-container">
            <header th:replace="~{fragments/global/header :: header_default}"></header>
            <nav th:replace="~{fragments/global/nav :: nav_default(~{active='Home'},~{subactive='Home'})}"></nav>
        </div>
```

I keep getting runtime exceptions for the extended text parts:

```
(~{title='Home'}) and similar for (~{active='Home'},~{subactive='Home'})
```

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error resolving fragment: "~{'fragments/global/head' :: head_default ('_arg0'=~{'title='Home''})}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "index" - line 8, col 11)

I have searched and tried the few variations I could find for a resolution but it keeps eluding me.

Comment: I also tried this which I found after posting this question.  And it too failed.  <head th:replace="~{fragments/global/head :: head_default(~{::title='Home'})}"></head>